# Display Dropdown for each column name from a Database PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am creating a small CSV export file for a database with a menu. I have the working code so far I just can't think of a way to do it. 
My aim is to have all the columns in a dropdown list and repeat this each time there is a column as the user will be able to decide where they want the columns displayed.
Eg if there were 5 rows in the table and x columns the drop-down box will be repeated x times.
I am stuck mainly on the user form of where to put a foreach loop in order to display a new drop down list with all the Column names more than once.

Thanks in advance

my code is below

User form

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" /> 



<div class="bootstrap-iso">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <form action = "Generate-csv.php"method="post">
     <div class="form-group">

<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

$sql = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM wpqf_student_registered';
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
echo '<select name="Select-Row">'; // Open your drop down box



while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    $columns[] = $row['Field'];

}
    foreach ($columns as $value) {

    echo '<option value="'.strip_tags($value).'">'.$value.'</option>';

}


echo '</select>';



?>

      <div>
       <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">
        Submit
       </button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSV format

```
<?php

$Option1 = $_POST["Select-Row"];
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($conn,"test");


header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=wpqf_student_registered.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array($Option1, 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));

// fetch the data

$rows = mysqli_query($conn ,'SELECT '.$Option1.' FROM wpqf_student_registered');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
fputcsv($output, $row);
}
fclose($output);

?>
```

Comment: If you change the one dropdown to allow multiple selection like `echo '<select name="Select-Row" multiple>';` then you will get an array of required fields

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: I am not actually very sure what you are asking us to help with to be honest

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want one dropdown to allow the user to select as many columns as they want in the resulting CSV file

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Then the `multiple` will be required.

Comment: Then `$_POST["Select-Row"]` will be an array, so you will need to change the PHP accordingly